# 95% prediction interval for price change

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, missing-data, prediction-interval

I have dataset with product prices observed during period of time. E.g.

**`day_number | price`** 
`1          | 10`
`3          | 11`
`6          | 8`
`12         | 9`
`15         | 12`
`20         | ??`

Price is recorded in data only on some days - it's missing for most of the days. If we assume that daily price changes are normally distributed with mean of zero and some standard deviation $X\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$, how can we calculate (based on data) 95% prediction interval for price on day 20?
I guess I need to first find most likely parameters for $X$ and then use formula for distribution of sum of random variables and get the prediction interval from there?

Comment: +1 Interesting question--and your proposed approach is good (although sensitive to the assumed normality of price changes, which will break down at low prices:you will need to check that assumption after estimating $\sigma_1$).  Please note that your question asks for a *prediction interval,* not a confidence interval.  But why did you apply the [tag:bayesian] tag? And the [tag:sampling] tag?  If anything, [tag:time-series] would be more appropriate, as well as [tag:missing-data].

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post according to your advice. I have initially set those tags based on my intuition about the problem, but I lack formal statistical knowledge so I guess those make no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, scale all the differences to obtain iid observations to estimate $\sigma_1^2$. For instance,

$Price(6) - Price(3) \sim N(0,3\sigma_1^2) => (Price(6) - Price(3)) / \sqrt{3} \sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$

If we denote scaled observations as $y_i$, the estimate of $\sigma_1^2$ is:

$ \sigma_1^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N y_i^2$

Then you can get a CI using that

$Price(20) \sim N(12,(20-15) * \sigma_1^2)$

This approach ignores the uncertainty in $\sigma_1^2$ estimation. If you want to take that into account as well, you'll have to use simulation.

Comment: It's a good approach, but falls short at the end. It will be important to account for the uncertainty in the estimate of $\sigma_1^2$ because it's going to be large in examples like this.  I believe there may be closed-form formulas for prediction limits.